# Не запускается Qt проект (Qt Creator)

Tags: qt, qtcreator

[image: Параметры сборки]
[image: Параметры запуска]

Пытаюсь открыть готовый проект с таким .pro файлом:

```
FORMS += \
    ../src/qt/forms/aboutdialog.ui \
    ../src/qt/forms/addressbookpage.ui \
    ../src/qt/forms/askpassphrasedialog.ui \
    ../src/qt/forms/coincontroldialog.ui \
    ../src/qt/forms/editaddressdialog.ui \
    ../src/qt/forms/helpmessagedialog.ui \
    ../src/qt/forms/intro.ui \
    ../src/qt/forms/openuridialog.ui \
    ../src/qt/forms/optionsdialog.ui \
    ../src/qt/forms/overviewpage.ui \
    ../src/qt/forms/receivecoinsdialog.ui \
    ../src/qt/forms/receiverequestdialog.ui \
    ../src/qt/forms/debugwindow.ui \
    ../src/qt/forms/sendcoinsdialog.ui \
    ../src/qt/forms/sendcoinsentry.ui \
    ../src/qt/forms/signverifymessagedialog.ui \
    ../src/qt/forms/transactiondescdialog.ui \

RESOURCES += \
    ../src/qt/bitcoin.qrc

win32:QMAKE_LFLAGS += -shared
```

(добавил только последнюю строку)
Выбивает : **Не удалось запустить программу. Путь или права недопустимы?**

Comment: Все дело в посленей строчке FORMS +=  `../src/qt/forms/transactiondescdialog.ui \ ` надо убрать ` \ ` в конце

Answer (score 0):

У меня в основном .pro файл выглядит так :3

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-08-31T15:16:30
#
#-------------------------------------------------
# core- для кода, gui(widgets) для элементов, serialbus это протокол КАН, concurrent - многопоточность.

QT       += core gui concurrent serialbus

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = terminal
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \
    PCANBasic.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

DISTFILES += \
    PCANBasic.dll \
    pict1.png \
    pict.ico
```

В том предоставленном к нашему вниманию  .pro файлу не хватает строчек:

```
  QT  += // прописываем блоки подключенных библиотек
  TARGET =  // цель изделия  (чтоб понять по сути нужна и нижняя строка, как ведите на моём примере это терминальное приложение)
  TEMPLATE = // прописываем что мы создаём (приложение либо библиотеку)
```

Хочу заметить что у меня есть догадка что вы не выложили весь .pro файл. 
И как по мне кажеться что проблемма не в настройках сборки и настройках запуска.

Ещё возможно что вы просто не удалили перед запуском проекта файлы (от при ведущего пользователя): Makefile, Makefile.Debug, Makefile.Release, <название_проекта>.pro.user. **Обязательно их удалите** (при вашем первом запуске проекта компьютер соберет эти файлы на вашем компьютере ) это файлы предыдущих компьютерных настроек (сборщика проекта) на другой компьютер, другого пользователя.

Comment: Они удаляются автоматически при выборе отчистить при клике правой кнопкой мыши по проекту

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить, или добавить конфигурацию запуска, это поможет обновить пути и настройки.
У Вас сейчас:

```
Конфигурация запуска: bitcoin-qt
```